# exited with non-zero code: 1 - using expo eject

Tags: android, gradle, expo

EXPO version 43.0.0 we just ejected it today and when runing expo run:android this pops up

```
BUILD FAILED in 32s
70 actionable tasks: 70 executed
Error: C:\Users\Dell\Documents\GitHub\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\android\gradlew.bat 
exited with non-zero code: 1
at ChildProcess.completionListener (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo- 
cli\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:65:13)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:520:26)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo- 
cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:293:5)
...
at spawnAsync (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo- 
cli\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:26:19)
at spawnGradleAsync (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo- 
cli\src\commands\run\android\spawnGradleAsync.ts:83:18)
at assembleAsync (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo- 
cli\src\commands\run\android\spawnGradleAsync.ts:57:16)
at actionAsync (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo- 
cli\src\commands\run\android\runAndroid.ts:143:9)
```

What could missing or wrong?

Comment: scroll up. the error will be above the "BUILD FAILED" message

Comment: oh i see a couple there now ok

Comment: thanks error was above now going through those